# What are the main rules differences between Zweihander and WFRP 4e?

Tags: edition-comparison, wfrp, wfrp-4e, zweihander

Considering these two sets of rules were inspired by WFRP 2e and came out recently, how do they compare?

From what I understand they both heavily use d10’s and have dark themed settings. They both use professions for character levelling and proficiencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of my head the biggest differences are...

1. They have different professions (but also many similar).
2. Progression/Leveling.
3. Injuries.
4. Healing is "harder" in Zwei, the rulebook makes clear that it is suppose to be hard to get healed, and that players should "suffer from their injuries". While in 4e healing is pretty straight forward, and also has more professions with healing capabilities.
5. The corruption systems, Zwei focuses more on good/evil choices while 4e focuses on corruption like a "force".
6. 4e has a more in dept "gods/religion"-section. And with it more(and different) rules about how "praying"-spells work.
7. The magic systems, 4e focuses more on the different winds while Zwei focuses more on magic being hard to learn and pull off, with requirements of items to be able to cast spells.